# SWTableViewCell cell scrollViewDidScroll message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: uitableview, xcode5, uiscrollviewdelegate

I used SWTableViewCell a third-party library to implement the swipe the UITableviewcell to open two buttons(save and delete) and click on those particular actions will occur.

See the screen shot i attached
[image]

When Swipe State is open and scroll the TableView then it crashes the app with message:

**[SearchCell cell] scrollViewDidScroll message sent to deallocated instance**

Help me how to solve this crash issue

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you fixed this already but set the delegate to nil when deallocating.

Answer (score 2):

SWTableViewCell.m

Please change dealloc to this

```
- (void)dealloc
 {
    _cellScrollView.delegate = nil;
     [self removeOldTableViewPanObserver];
 }
```

Everything will be OK